# How to move down this balloon in scroll with css

Tags: html, css, animation, scroll, effects

Hello again everyone I am creating a project for my class students.

My question is how should I move the balloon down at the ground side on scroll with css only.

I only want to move the balloon down to the ground. It will look like an animation video that which the balloon is going down and the scene is changing. I mean the balloon goes down from 1 scene to 2 scenes and then so on I hope you will get my point.

**Note: Only ballon goes down on scroll**

THanks in advance

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Moving Balloon animation</title>
    <style>
        *{
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
        }
        .container{
            position:absolute;
            z-index:-1;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            overflow-y: auto;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            perspective: 10px;
            background-color: black;;
        }
        .container .slide{
            position:relative;
            overflow:hidden;
            z-index:-1;
            width: 100%;
            display:flex;
            float:left;
            background-color: green;
            height: 100%;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
        }
        .container .slide img{
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="slide slide1">
            <img src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WO-MdeOXS72JtuwDE-z6y_d0Q57uCF2x/view?usp=sharing" class="back" alt="">
            <img src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ekSyrp8QOTH8o4bF7D2jQoNWeA0g4vor/view?usp=sharing" alt="">
            <img src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UbXtFU1-57p1zb-EmqTQfacStDYD_hmr/view?usp=sharing" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="slide slide2">
            <img src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WO-MdeOXS72JtuwDE-z6y_d0Q57uCF2x/view?usp=sharing" class="back" alt="">
            <img src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/18s52rMJQZYd_zsyBMnmjAfjJZ0C2I8uq/view?usp=sharing" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="slide slide3">
            <img src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WO-MdeOXS72JtuwDE-z6y_d0Q57uCF2x/view?usp=sharing" class="back" alt="">
            <img src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lHL54riQRwY5yS7KCLCu46Y2NDGfePDo/view?usp=sharing" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="slide slide4">
            <img src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WO-MdeOXS72JtuwDE-z6y_d0Q57uCF2x/view?usp=sharing" class="back" alt="">
            <img src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GIK0pyiC8yKY-o57R1f3adG7oaBjG2NH/view?usp=sharing" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="slide slide5">
            <img src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WO-MdeOXS72JtuwDE-z6y_d0Q57uCF2x/view?usp=sharing" class="back" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="slide slide6">
            <img src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WO-MdeOXS72JtuwDE-z6y_d0Q57uCF2x/view?usp=sharing" class="back" alt="">
            <img src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SUUXzqcOhZ6Wr3viiwAU6HlIHRdUAka4/view?usp=sharing" alt="">
            <img src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Is415tDvd_Rx4HXWGRYW4eleJDgF3wyB/view?usp=sharing" alt="">
            <img src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xwXOBHVSurxoAkuMs7oNDoKOdu9d15M1/view?usp=sharing" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Only balloon]

Comment: Can you share your images on this codepen. So I can easily check and find out the solutions 
https://codepen.io/ashok-kannan-dev/pen/eYyvapB

Comment: Here is the link of assets https://www.mediafire.com/file/hlnq30istxkg1rc/balloons+asstes.zip/file